# Moodle can't redirect to page after installation

Tags: moodle

I have just installed Moodle on my web-server. Everything was OK until I came to page where I saw this text: "This page should automatically redirect. If nothing is happening please use the continue link below. Continue."

When I click on Continue, the same page shows again. I deleted all data from moodledata folder (saw it on this site), but I have the same problem again and again. What can be a problem here and how to solve it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The first step to do is to enable debugging. I assume you can not access site administration anymore so you have to enable debugging in the config.php file. The file is located in /path/to/moodle/config.php (that means in the root folder of your Moodle installation).
The first lines should look like that in config.php. That means you have to add the 4 lines which are under $CFG = new stdClass();

```
<?php  // Moodle configuration file

unset($CFG);
global $CFG;
$CFG = new stdClass();
@error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);   // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
@ini_set('display_errors', '1');         // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
$CFG->debug = (E_ALL | E_STRICT);   // === DEBUG_DEVELOPER - NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
$CFG->debugdisplay = 1;              // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
```

After that open Moodle in your browser. A debug message will be displayed. Post the error message in order to get additional help so solve the problem.

Comment: This is shown after I updated config.php:
randjelovic.in.rs/moodleproblem.jpg
I've sent a link because text is so long for a comment.

Comment: Sorry, I can't open your link. My browser tells me it is too dangerous.. Could you post the message here?

Comment: Maybe it is because I don't have SSL certificate. Message will be posted in next 3 comments.

Comment: Warning: Zend OPcache API is restricted by "restrict_api" configuration directive in /www/webvol4/u6/g7u7rlct97d0wap/randjelovic.in.rs/public_html/medfak/moodle/admin/index.php on line 93

Notice: Undefined property: DOMAttr::$name in /www/webvol4/u6/g7u7rlct97d0wap/randjelovic.in.rs/public_html/medfak/moodle/lib/htmlpurifier/HTMLPurifier/Lexer/DOMLex.php on line 220
Notice: Undefined property: DOMAttr::$value in /www/webvol4/u6/g7u7rlct97d0wap/randjelovic.in.rs/public_html/medfak/moodle/lib/htmlpurifier/HTMLPurifier/Lexer/DOMLex.php on line 220

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: DOMElement::$tagName in /www/webvol4/u6/g7u7rlct97d0wap/randjelovic.in.rs/public_html/medfak/moodle/lib/htmlpurifier/HTMLPurifier/Lexer/DOMLex.php on line 180
Skip to main content
× This page should automatically redirect. If nothing is happening please use the continue link below.
(Continue)
Error output, so disabling automatic redirect.

Comment: I am not sure, but seems, that you have an old PHP version. Recent moodle requires PHP7.0. What are your system specifications? If you go directly to that URL (append to the moodle base url)  /admin/environment.php on my local machine that is http://localhost/moodle/admin/environment.php